# Find all synonyms of word X that rhyme with word Y

Tags: curated-data, wolfram-alpha-queries

Given two words x and y, I'd like to find the set of all words that rhyme with x and are synonymous with y. Is this possible with `WordData` or `WolframAlpha`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that wolfram|Alpha wasn't good enough, by RhymeZone is a great site for this, and they even support near rhymes. Here's an example:

[image]

```
Rhymes[r_] := Rhymes[r] = Module[{url, links, rhy},
    url=StringTemplate["http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=`1`&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y"][r];
    Check[links=Import[url,"Hyperlinks"],Return@$Failed];
    rhy=Flatten[StringCases[#,"http://www.rhymezone.com/r/d="~~w__:>StringReplace[w,"_"->" "]]&/@links];
    Return @ rhy
]

Synonyms[s_] := Synonyms[s] = Module[{url, links, syn},
    url=StringTemplate["http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=`1`&typeofrhyme=syn&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y"][s];
    Check[links=Import[url,"Hyperlinks"],Return@$Failed];
    syn=Flatten[StringCases[#,"http://www.rhymezone.com/r/d="~~w__:>StringReplace[w,"_"->" "]]&/@links];
    Return @ syn
]

RhymesWithXSynonymWithY[x_, y_] := Intersection[Rhymes@x, Synonyms@y]
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a start....

```
x = "healed";
y = "pay";

Intersection[
 WolframAlpha["synonyms of " <> y, {{"Synonyms:WordData", 1}, "ComputableData"}, InputAssumptions -> {"*MC.%7E-_*WordData-"}], 
 WolframAlpha["rhymes with " <> x, {{"Rhyme:WordData", 1}, "ComputableData"}, 
 PodStates -> {"Rhyme:WordData__More"}, InputAssumptions -> {"*MC.%7E-_*WordData-"}]
]
```

> `{yield}`

Meh, this isn't exhaustive, but it's as good as W|A can do it seems.